# which is best array_search or in_array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a large while loop function, every time it gets loaded for check with current **URL** name.
So I need to know which one is better to check the **URL** name in large array within the while loop,
`in_array()` or `array_search()` function.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Based on the documentation of [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) and [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php), I'd think that it mainly depends on what you want to do with the information: if you need the entry, use `array_search`, if you just want to check if the url exists in the array, `in_array` should be enough.

Comment: Depend on the time, which is best?

Comment: After long time reference, and depends on my requirement, I have choose in_array function.

Answer (score 67):

If it's a large array **and** in a loop, neither is "best". Instead use [`array_flip()`](http://www.php.net/array_flip) on your array, so urls become keys. And use [`isset()`](http://www.php.net/isset) to check for the presence.

Comment: Thanks Mario, This is alternate method. But compare this function with in_array and array_search function, is this function will gives speed result ?

Comment: PHP is MUCH faster at checking for existence of keys than values. If you have a large set of unique values that you need to frequently refer to, always set them as keys.

Comment: For this to work, the original values must be integers or strings. While it applies to OP’s question, it cannot be used as a general solution.

Answer (score 59):

There's no real answer here. So I tried it, myself.

```php
$haystack = array
(
    'apple',
    'banana',
    'cherry',
    'lemon',
    'lime',
    'orange',
    'potato',
    'rutabaga'
);
$haySize = count($haystack);

$loops = isset( $_SERVER['argv'][1] ) ? $_SERVER['argv'][1] : 10000;
// echo 'Loops: ' . $loops . "\n";

$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < $loops; $i++)
{
    $needle = $haystack[ $i % $haySize ];
}
$zeroTime = microtime(true) - $start;
// echo sprintf('%0.3f', $zeroTime * 1000) . ' ms : zero time' . "\n";

$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < $loops; $i++)
{
    $needle = $haystack[ $i % $haySize ];
    $dummy = array_search($needle, $haystack);
}
echo sprintf('%0.3f', (microtime(true) - $start - $zeroTime) * 1000) . ' ms : array_search' . "\n";

$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < $loops; $i++)
{
    $needle = $haystack[ $i % $haySize ];
    $dummy = in_array($needle, $haystack);
}
echo sprintf('%0.3f', (microtime(true) - $start - $zeroTime) * 1000) . ' ms : in_array' . "\n";
    echo sprintf('%0.3f', (microtime(true) - $start) * 1000).' ms : in_array'."\n";
```

For a typical use case, in_array wins, but the difference is negligible:

```
22.662 ms : array_search
22.104 ms : in_array
```

Updated 2014-01-02: added noop loop to "zero the scale". Running PHP 5.4.17 on a new MacBook pro, this is a typical result:

```
24.462 ms : array_search
24.984 ms : in_array
```

Comment: +1 for giving some benchmarks. I'd like to add to this by pointing out that the array_flip/isset method provided by @mario is much faster than array_search and in_array, provided the array is flipped outside the loop.

Added at the bottom of your test code:
`$flipped = array_flip($haystack);
$start = microtime(true);
for ($i=0; $i<$loops; $i++)
{
    $needle = $haystack[$i % $haySize];
    $dummy = isset($flipped[$needle]);
}
echo sprintf('%0.3f', (microtime(true) - $start) * 1000).' ms : isset'."\n";`

25.281 ms : array_search
22.345 ms : in_array
4.895 ms : isset

Comment: A good point. This would be useful if you need to search for multiple values. If you're only searching through it once, though, it would be worse to incur the cost of constructing the hash. I considered the "typical case" to be searching the array for a single value.

Comment: The original question is hard to understand, but he may be talking about a case where array_flip is indeed the best solution.

Comment: @PatrickFisher In your test you calculate loop time, `$needle` initialization and then time of needed function. That results definitely can't show difference between `in_array` and `array_search`.

Comment: It does show which is faster. The loop time calculation will not have an effect. You are right that the proportion of the difference will be reduced due to the `$needle` assignment within the loop. I assume the assignment is fast enough that it isn't a big influence on the result. Have you tested this assumption?

Comment: @PatrickFisher Yes, I tested it. But from time to time I had different results +-10%. Looks like this functions are even. Test source is [here](https://github.com/nafigator/php-bench/blob/master/Tests/ArraySearchVsInArray.php).

Comment: I suspect the problem is that you're starting and stopping the timer every time, when the timer is only accurate to microseconds. That's the whole point of a large number of repetitions - to increase the time to something measurable. You're also only testing the worst case, which could produce a result which does not match the real world. My even distribution was meant to approximate expected case.

Comment: I would test the impact of the loop increment and the needle assignment by having a "control" loop which times everything but the function call in question. Then subtract that time to get the time attributable to the function under test.

Comment: @PatrickFisher Look at the test code carefully. I get a sum of timer calculations exactly that functions I'm interesting in, without any other function influence. And it's pretty measurable.

Answer (score 7):

it's different function
in_array - return true if find value
array_search - return position if find value

```
$a = array('a', 'b');
var_dump(in_array('a', $a)); // return true
var_dump(array_search('a', $a)); // return 0 
if (array_search('a', $a)) - false
```

Comment: Thanks AmdY, Yes you are correct. But I need which function to get speed result.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only goal is to check if an URL exists in the array I'd go for in_array. Altough the best way is having keys set so you can just search by array key. That way you save alot of looping.

```
$searchword = "test";
echo $array[$searchword];
```

Comment: I think you support for array_key_exists() function, Exactly I need which function to get reduce our time for search.

Answer (score 0):

It's up to your array-size. 
-If you have a small array(like < 500k 32bit-key), 
in_array and array_search give you same performance
isset(array[needle]) make no sense because of flip()

-By big arrays(like >  1m 32bit key)
There are really big difference between in_array and isset(array[needle])

Answer (score -1):

```
array1=array("a"=>"one","b"=>"two"); 

if(in_array("one",$array))
{
  echo "array exit"; 
 }
 else
  {
     echo " array not exist"; 
  }

echo "</br>";
//example of array_search():
 $b1=array("a"=>"one","b"=>"two");
    echo array_search("one",$b1);
```

in_array return true and false value and array_search return key of the array