# PHP in_array() associative array issue

Tags: php, arrays, ajax

Strange PHP in_array issue tripping me. Not a PHP expert, but I'm a bit exhausted, and can't seem to catch the syntax or property I might be erring on.

This is what I'm trying to do:

- Get a CSV file, turn it into an associative array
- Look for a code in the array. It is a dynamic variable I get from a simple form submission.
- Send a "Message" response to if the code exists, else send an "Error" response

To my understanding, the code below should've worked, but strangely enough, the moment I add the "else", the response always returns "error" (like, it never enters the if, or it's getting reset for every iteration to error).

If I remove the "else" condition inside for loop, it's working as expected, but I need to catch the error. Also tried strict comparison, no dice!

Any help is appreciated! Thank you once again.

```
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file($file,FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES));
$keys = array_shift($csv);

foreach ($csv as $i=>$row) {
    $csv[$i] = array_combine($keys, $row);
}
for ($j=0; $j<count($csv); $j++) {
    if (in_array($code, $csv[$j])) {
      $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Found'));
      die($output);
    } 
    else {
      $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Not Found'));
      die($output);
    }
}
```

Comment: You reference `$code` in your `in_array()` but where is it created?

Comment: where is the value of `$code`?

Comment: what is the value of `$code`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a `die()` both in the `if` *and* the `else`-block, your code will only test the first iteration and then stop executing. That's why it works when you omit the `else`.

Change it to:

```
for ($j=0; $j<count($csv); $j++) {
    if (in_array($code, $csv[$j])) {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Found'));
        die($output);
    } 
}

$output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Not Found'));
die($output);
```

Since you have a `die()` in the `if`-block, any code after the loop will only be executed if the expression in the `if`-block never evaluates as true.

Comment: Oh &*$%, that was it. Thank you Magnus. I knew it was something basic. Sorry about the noob moment.

Comment: @Deep - No worries. We've all been there. :-) (and still are, from time to time).

Answer (score 1):

You should use [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) to find by value in an associative array instead of using `in_array` like:

```
if (array_search($code, $csv[$j]))
```

Comment: Thank you for the response @Lovepreet. That wasn't my issue however. The condition was being met, but it was the iteration issue as Magnus points out. However, I'm curious - is there a specific documentation, or speed-test which justifies using array_search over in_array? From what I've read here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518404/which-is-best-array-search-or-in-array - in_array() seems faster. Thanks again :)

Comment: @Deep - Those two functions does different things. `in_array()` is simply checking if a value exists and returns a boolean, while `array_search()` will return the corresponding key, if the value is found. In your case, `in_array()` makes more sense.

Comment: When using `array_search()`, you should always check it with: `array_search($value, $array) !== false` since it can return `0` if the value is found and it has the key `0`. If you do as the above, you can get a false negative.

Comment: Hey, yes! I knew about that. I was just curious as to how/ why it was suggested to use array_search here. As you mention, I was just looking for an "exists" check and send a response, so opted for the former. :)

Answer (score 0):

You did not defined $code variable in your code and also you can do in code is

```
if(!empty($code)&& in_array($code,$csv[$j])){

}
```

you need to check $code variable empty or not!